# Automatically Updating the records after inserting in jpa Spring Boot

Tags: javascript, java, spring, jwt

I have create a jpa entity Order , OrderItems, OrderBatches and OrderBatchStages and created unidirectional OneToMany Relationships between them. The Problem is that when i insert a new record (new order) there is no any error in the insertion the order is inserting in the database but the issue is that the inserted rows are updated automatically. My Entities are..
**Order**

```
    @Entity
@Table(name = "orders")

public class OrderBean
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "order_id")

    private Long orderId;

    @Column(name = "order_date")
    private Date orderDate;

    @Column(name = "total_quantity")
    private Integer totalQuantity;

    @Column(name = "order_no")
    private Long orderNo;

    @ManyToOne
    private RecipeBean recipeBean;

    @ManyToOne
    private UnitBean unitBean;

    private Integer active = 1;

    private Boolean releaseMaterialStatus = false;

    @Transient
    private Integer productId;

    @Transient
    private Integer unitId;

    @Transient
    private String productName;

    @Transient
    private String unitName;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private OrderStatusTypes status;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private OrderStatusStages stage;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "orders_id")
    private List<OrderItems> orderItems;


    private Integer stageId;


    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "order_orderbatch_id")
    private Set<OrderBatches> batchesSet  = new HashSet<OrderBatches>();

    private boolean productionFinish;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private OrderType type;
```

**OrderBatches**

```
@Entity
@DynamicUpdate(false)
public class OrderBatches {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long batchId;

    @Column(name = "batch_no")
    private double batchNo;

    @Column(name = "batch_code")
    private String batchCode;

    private Long orderId;

    private double quantity;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private BatchStatus status;

    @Column(name = "batch_time")
    private String batchTime;

    @JoinColumn(name = "batchstageid")
    @JsonIgnoreProperties({ "hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler" })
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)

    private List<OrderBatchStages> batchStages;
```

**OrderBatchStages**

```
@Entity
@DynamicUpdate(false)
public class OrderBatchStages
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "stage_number")
    private int stageNumber;

    @Column(name = "stage_title")
    private String stageTitle;

    @Column(name = "batch_Id")
    private Long batchId;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private BatchStageStatus status;

    private Boolean qc;
```

**OrderItems**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "order_items")
public class OrderItems
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;
    private Integer produtId;
    private Double requiredQuantity;
    private Integer status;
    private Double stockQuantity;
    private Boolean exceed;
    private String productName;
```

[image: The update queries are running like this]

Comment: What does this have to do with Angular?

Comment: yeah but my question is why these unwanted update queries are running ? i think there are problems in the relationships